# Using multiple network interfaces on k3s

Tags: k3s, cni

I'm sort of a newbie in k3s I know that in kubernetes, the multus plugin allows to to have multiple network interfaces attached to a pod, is there a way to have the same result with k3s?

There is this guide to install the plugin on k3s but I did  not manage to make it work, has anyone succeded?
https://gist.github.com/janeczku/ab5139791f28bfba1e0e03cfc2963ecf

Answer (score 0):

Update cni bin path i.e /var/lib/rancher/k3s/data/current/bin and cni config path i.e /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/cni/net.d in Daemonset of Multus
and it should work.

Daemon set should look like

- name: cni
  hostPath:
  path: /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/cni/net.d
- name: cnibin
  hostPath:
  path: /var/lib/rancher/k3s/data/current/bin

Logs on multus before updating Daemonset

```
kubectl logs kube-multus-ds-knpjs -n kube-system -p
Defaulted container "kube-multus" out of: kube-multus, install-multus-binary (init)
2023-11-07T17:23:05Z [verbose] multus-daemon started
2023-11-07T17:25:05Z [error] failed to find the primary CNI plugin: failed to find the cluster master CNI plugin: could not find a plugin configuration in /host/etc/cni/net.d
2023-11-07T17:25:05Z [error] failed to create the configuration manager for the primary CNI plugin: failed to find the cluster master CNI plugin: could not find a plugin configuration in /host/etc/cni/net.d
```

Logs on multus after updating Daemonset

```
kubectl logs kube-multus-ds-49h4j -n kube-system
Defaulted container "kube-multus" out of: kube-multus, install-multus-binary (init)
2023-11-07T17:30:56Z [verbose] multus-daemon started
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple logical does the trick, without needing to tinker in the multus repo:

```
ln -s  /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/cni/net.d /etc/cni/net.d
```